# Jobs chaining in Quatz 2.x .net

Tags: c#, .net, quartz-scheduler, job-scheduling

Is there a simple example for jobs chaining in Quarts for .net? I'm struggling to find one for version 2.x.

Would really appreciate some help.

Comment: Google tells that there is a simple sample [here](http://www.obsidianscheduler.com/blog/job-chaining-in-quartz-and-obsidian-scheduler/). It's a Java implementation, but you may not have problems porting it to c#.